# How can I use Visual basic to download the file I want in URl?

Tags: vbscript

I'd like to downlowd one file chosen form this url

> http://www.senao.com.tw/download.aspx

But I need to use Visual Basic to autodownload form this url.
Without click on it. so, can I finish the work?

Answer (score 0):

For VB.NET:

```
My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(address, destinationFileName)
```

For any language on Windows that supports COM: see [`URLDownloadToFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123.aspx).

Comment: And I don't know how to make my VB supports COM!